# Django Internationalization and localization instead of /en use a specific domain for each language

Tags: django

i have 3 domains, which will be one website, just that each one will serve a language
ej: (right now i am in dev mode so i only have localhost to test)

```
drenglish.com for 'en'
drspanish.com for 'es_ES'
drportugueses for 'pt_BR'
```

automatically Internationalization and localization works with /lang added to the urls, but i dont want that
i tried transurlvania but cant figure it out, is there an easy way to use my translated  po file and tie it to a domain ?
site framework seem to maybe be the answer, but i get lost when they tell to create different settings and urls files for each domain so you can add the right SITE_ID

i am starting to use i18n for the internationalization and localization

settings;

```
 middleware: 'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware'
 USE_I18N = True

 #drspanish.com = ID 5
 #drportugueses = ID 4
 #drenglish.com = ID 1

 SITE_ID = 1

 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _ LANGUAGES = (
     ('en', _('English')),
     ('pt_BR', _('Portuguese')),
     ('es_ES', _('Spanish')), )

 LOCALE_PATHS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'), )
```

urls(main);

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    #urls for english + global
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')), #for allauth
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')), #for allauth
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')), ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # comment out this line from the +... if the website is live, its only to serve image in debug mode

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url('', include('home.urls')), #for allauth
    url('contact', include('contact.urls')),
    url(r'^videos/', include('video.urls')),
    url(r'^dash/', include('UDash.urls')),
    url(r'^appointment/', include('appointment.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^cart/', include('cart.urls')),
    url(r'^shop/', include('shop.urls')), )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a middleware to set your language depending on the domain you are accessing. For example, create a middleware SetLanguageToDomain which will look like this,

```
from django.utils import translation
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site


class SetLanguageToDomain:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        if current_site == 'drenglish':
            user_language = 'en'
        elif current_site == 'drspanish':
            user_language = 'es_ES'
        else:
            user_language = 'pt_BR'
        translation.activate(user_language)
        request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

Then add this to your middlewares after the locale middleware.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I forgot to ask you which Django version are you on. This will work on Django 2.+, if you are on django 1.8+ then you need to use the old style middleware, but the logic is exactly the same.

Comment: i added a folder middleware at root(drLandivar is the project name) of the project, inside i added __init__.py and SetLanguageToDomain.py, in settings i added 'drLandivar.middleware.SetLanguageToDomain', but with that middleware, i cannot run the website {ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drLandivar.middleware'}

Comment: I am on django 2.0 with python 3.7

Comment: Write your middleware inside a middleware.py file and place it in one of your apps that is included in the installed_apps of your application. Then the new middleware should work. So, if you have an app called "main" for example, you add the middleware.py file next to the models.py and views.py files inside that app, and then in your middlewares you will add `main.middlewares.SetLanguageToDomain`.

Comment: Yes you are totally right ! thank you so much for your time its much appreciated, have a great one !!!